# Getting nearest point but with a filter conditional in QGIS 3.4?

Tags: qgis, point, distance

I have two point layers in CSV files, each with about 500 points/rows. Each point in both layers has a year column (attribute). I know how to use Distance Matrix to find the nearest point. BUT: For each point in Layer 1, I want to find the nearest point from Layer 2 that has one of the three previous years to the point in Layer 1. For example, if point x in Layer 1 has 1989 in the Year column, then it should search for nearest point only out of all points in Layer 2 that have 1986, 1987, 1988 in the Year column, and return the nearest one.

Comment: the CSV can't contain a point (i.e. a geometry). You can create geometries from a csv file, and then use the spatial layer to find the nearest neighbors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a virtual layer that will join the two layers and apply the desired filtering.

go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the query

```sql
SELECT pt1.id, pt2.id,
       ROUND(MIN(ST_Distance(pt1.geometry, pt2.geometry)),2) AS distance
FROM point_layer_1 AS pt1, point_layer_2 AS pt2
WHERE pt2.year_column BETWEEN pt1.year_column - 3 AND pt1.year_column - 1
GROUP BY pt1.id
ORDER BY distance DESC
```

The `group by` will ensure we get a single row for each row in layer1. Because we `order by` distance, the group by will retain the 1st entry, i.e. the nearest one.

edit: according to this [doc](https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html#aggregate_queries_can_contain_non_aggregate_result_columns_that_are_not_in_the_group_by_clause), since there is a single `min()` in use, we could drop the `order by` clause and still get `pt2.id` referring to the closest point. This would however fail should a secondary `min` or `max` be added to the query.