# How to connect nearest points to increasing closest date

Tags: qgis, date, geometry-generator

Given a points collection layer containing the data field ("DATADIA") with the date (YYYYY-MM-dd), how could I connect the nearest points in order of increasing date?

The expression should work with an expression for Geometry generator that draw a line.

I add a screenshot with a hand-made simulation of the expected result example

[image]

**Unsuccessful solution attempt**:

With the following SQL query to create a Virtual Layer that connects each point to its closest point with the first upper date I get the following result:

```
SELECT ST_ShortestLine(r.geometry, p.geometry) AS geom,
       p.DATETEMPS AS pid,
       r.DATETEMPS AS rid,
       ROUND(MIN(ST_Distance(r.geometry, p.geometry)),2) AS distance
FROM Layer_1 AS p, Layer_2 AS r
WHERE p.DATETEMPS > r.FECHA
GROUP BY p.DATETEMPS
ORDER BY distance DESC
```

[image]

What modifications or corrections would have to be made so that the Virtual Layer query draw for each point its corresponding line as I show in this expected result?

[image]

Comment: Distance Matrix can do part of this, you most likely need to add an expression for dates https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html?highlight=matrix#distance-matrix

Comment: I dont understand why all your features arent connected

Comment: At the beginning, this example is handmade. Now I also observe that there is a point not connected (the point value 2023-04-22). This is an error. According to what I am looking for, this point should be connected to the nearest point with value 2023-04-23.

Comment: See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/380598/88814