# Making Nearest neighbour join with attribute condition in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, spatial-join, proximity, one-to-one

I have two line layers in QGIS:

- Input Layer A: Street Segments
- Layer B: Traffic Data

and would like to perform the nearest neighbour join with a condition (where the same street name is equal- one-by-one join).

"Join attributes by nearest with condition" from ProcessX is not working correctly, I tried it different times (no correct results).

I uploaded an example dataset here
https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/d67ac6c3-614e-4752-a50f-e52f087c1826

Do you have other solutions for this problem?

[image]

Layer A Road network hierachy (Lines) condition field street name "STRNAME" Text (String)

Layer B Traffic Modell (Lines) condition field street name "STRNAME" Text (String) field for nearest neighbor analysis to join Traffic numbers (Dezimal/Double)

I tried with two point layers (centroids from line) but again no result

I uploaded an example dataset here
swisstransfer.com/d/d67ac6c3-614e-4752-a50f-e52f087c1826

Comment: Can you share the data ?

Comment: Looks like there is a question for you @MrXsquared ^_^

Comment: Here is a [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/335909/getting-nearest-point-but-with-a-filter-conditional-in-qgis-3-4/335914#335914) using a virtual layer

Comment: I have already seen your issue on github, but cannot anwser due to missing informations. Please show the settings you use as well as details about your layers, attributes and field types. If possible you can also provide an example with data.

Comment: So far everything looks ok and correct. I cannot find an error in your settings. So the reason must be somewhere within your data or an unknown bug in the script. Is there any chance to share example data? Otherwise it will be really hard to find the cause. Or are there any warnings or errors in the log? The only thing I can tell from here, is that for a true 1-1 join you need to uncheck "Join Features more than once" and/or set Join x nearest... to 1 unless each name is unique.

Comment: Finally i got good results when i used the second condition OR A SECOND CONDITION and then same comparison operator and expression. dont know why it makes a difference. but actually im happy to have good results.

Comment: Depends on what it was set to before. If you only want to use one condition, the second one should be set to AND and the expressions to empty and = as explained in the description (default settings). However, glad it is working now.

Comment: Still not working as i recognized. ive uploaded an example with data here https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/d67ac6c3-614e-4752-a50f-e52f087c1826

Comment: @Nabil I tried with your testdata and its working perfectly fine for me, running on QGIS 3.32.0 (Windows 11). Can you again show all your exact settings based on your provided testdata and also show the output you get as well as the expected output? https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE25l.png

Comment: @MrXsquared
Thank you very much for your help. 
We reimported again the Data to qgis and made a Join from Centroid to Centroid (Lines to Centroids) with your PlugIn which finally worked great for us. 
Lines to Lines didnt work so well.
But the result is really good now.
Great PlugIn and thx :)